# Cumulative sum (progressive total)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I have a cube with the dimension CreatedOn (Time type) and the measure IssueOpened.  I need to get the cumulative sum for IssueOpened.

For example:

```
2009  IssueOpened=7   OpenedOnTheEndOfPeriod=7
2010  IssueOpened=12  OpenedOnTheEndOfPeriod=19
2011  IssueOpened=2   OpenedOnTheEndOfPeriod=21
```

So, I have created the calculated member:

```
sum([CreatedOn].[Y-Q-M].currentmember.level.members(0):[CreatedOn].[Y-Q-M].currentmember.prevmember, Measures.[IssueOpened])
```

[image]

But it looks like it doesn't work as I want.  Start of dimension:

[image]

And it looks like a truth at the end of dimension:

[image]

May be the error on the first member of Time dimension? What do I need to fix to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever looked at http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-articles/62-design/367-inventory-management-calculations-in-sql-server-analysis-services-2005-by-richard-tkachuk. This is a must read if you want to attemp anything like you are doing.

To calculate a running total, you should use a member like this one :

```
set Q as Nonempty( Order( [CreatedOn].[Y-Q-M].Members,[Measures].[IssueOpened], ASC ) 
                         ,[Measures].[IssueOpened] )

Member [Measures].[RunningTotal] as Sum(
    Head( Q, ( [Measures].[Level], [CreatedOn].[Y-Q-M].CurrentMember ) )
   ,[Measures].[IssueOpened] )
```